# CHMOD on a folder for image uploads

Tags: php

I'm uploading files from users (for use in news articles) to a particular folder on my linux-based site. I've set the directory to 755 as per other questions I've seen here... and removing Execute permission results in the images there not being served (403 is thrown).

But... I don't really understand the security implications here. If I leave the folder as 755, doesn't that mean a user could upload a script through my upload form, and then execute it???

Comment: And what about permissions of those images? (`chmod -r`)

Comment: The execute permission on a directory means being able to enumerate its contents, not being able to execute things within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 = execute / access directory
2 = write 
4 = read
```

The initial 7 means that the owner can execute, read and write. 5 means 1+4 which is execute and read.

5 in the middle position means that group members can read end execute, and in the last position it means that everyone can read and execute.

If the user that runs the web server owns the files and directories set to 755, users may upload into and read from that directory if you provide such functionality in your scripts.

Files users upload should not be put in a directory which the public can access before you are sure that they are safe. PHP puts them in `/tmp/` initially.

PHP files however is not executed directly, they are just read into PHP which runs it. The execute flag therefore doesn't mean anything in this case. If you want to restrict running of PHP-scripts in a directory, you can use a `.htaccess`-file.

Comment: Ok but I've set this file to 755... why is it giving a 403? :(

Comment: It might not be just the file access flags, the web servers configuration can also restrict access to files. But make sure that the parent directories have 4 and 1 set for the web servers user also.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate permission for images and other file types on linux (or any other OS I know). Any image will need 'execute' permission to be viewed.

You must limit your users to upload only images on script side (e.g. PHP uploader script must check file extension before uploading). I can't recommend any exact thing, as you haven't mentioned how images are uploaded to the server by users. Anyway it must be checked before uploading permissions won't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

chmod command set permission for Owner/Group/World respectively. r is equal 4, w 2 and x for execute is 1. You set 5 for world means that users are able to read and execute. If you desire to make user permission writable  you should set last digit 7.